# Swift Query Into Firebase Firestore Nested Array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have nested data that I'd like to display in a tableView.

My data is structured like so...

```
/users
    /userid
         name: "John"
         age: 23
         /likedPosts
            0:post1
            1:post2
```

For the tableview I'd like to display these posts (which have their own collection of data).

In order to do that I need to...

1) Get the count of the array and

2) Query the users likedPost array values to get the content of the post.

I'm currently using the getDocument function and can't figure it out.

for example...

```
func getUserLikedPosts() {
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        let userFS = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.uid)
        userFS.getDocument(completion: { (snapshot, error) in
            print(snapshot?)

        })
    }
}
```

This doesn't even print out the nested array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
func getUserLikedPosts() {
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    let userFS = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.uid).collection(“likedPosts”)
    userFS.getDocuments(completion: { (snapshot, error) in
        print(snapshot?)

    })
}
}
```

With Firestore you need to drill down to the actual node you want, unlike Firebase where you can access child snapshots.

So after a quick discussion, with the OP, it was that the user in question didn’t have a likedPost object.

To access the array (Please be aware I haven’t tested this code, it is an example):

```
If let doc = document, let array = doc[“likedPost] as NSArray {
print(array)
}
```

Comment: It isn't a collection.  It's an array in the document.

Comment: Ahh I see. Does it print out the rest of the data?

Comment: No it says nil.  If I print it out the way i was doing it - it shows all of the top level data ... ie name & age.  But doesn't print out even the header "likedPosts"

Comment: Really daft, but have you checked that the user you are trying to access has likedPosts as an object in its hierarchy?

Comment: Good catch! haha so there wasn't anything for the user...but still nothing with both of the ways we were printing...i found if we do `if let userInfo = document { print(userInfo.data()) }` THEN is shows up in the console as....`<__NSArrayM 0x1c0c5f050>(
faskdjfl,
asdf
)` - the gibberish is my quick making a post ;)

Comment: figured it out...`let userLikedPostsArray = document!["likedPosts"] as! NSArray` yewww! thanks for the spot!